# Python Program to determine greater, lesser, equal

Tags: python

I need to write a program that will tell me if the the first of two number is greater, lesser, or equal

```
def g_l_e (arg_one, arg_two) :
if (arg_one) > (arg_two): 
    answer = print('greater')
if (arg_one) < (arg_two):
    answer = print('lesser')
if (arg_one) == (arg_two):
    answer = print('equal')
return (answer)

g_l_e(1, 2) 
g_l_e(2, 1)  
g_l_e(2, 2)
```

The answers come back:
lesser
greater
equal

but when I submit it for grading it says:
FAIL - incorrect output for g_l_e(1, 2)
expected ['lesser'] but got [None]
your function should have a 'return' satement

I do not understand why this could be happening. It says [None] for every output.

Comment: You are assigning a print statement to the answer variable. You need to assign the string to the answer variable and then return that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` statements return type `None`. And you are assigning the `result` variable the return value of the `print` statements. What you want is the following:

```
def g_l_e (arg_one, arg_two) :
    if (arg_one) > (arg_two): 
        answer = 'greater'
    if (arg_one) < (arg_two):
        answer = 'lesser'
    if (arg_one) == (arg_two):
        answer = 'equal'
    print(answer)
    return (answer)

g_l_e(1, 2) 
g_l_e(2, 1)  
g_l_e(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try this you would realise that your function does not return anything

```
def g_l_e (arg_one, arg_two) :
  if (arg_one) > (arg_two): 
      answer = print('greater')
  if (arg_one) < (arg_two):
      answer = print('lesser')
  if (arg_one) == (arg_two):
      answer = print('equal')
  return (answer)


answer = g_l_e(1, 2)
print(answer)
```

You have to replace the print() statements with actual strings.